# Sql syntax error when insert into table with python on mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to implement the code [on this video](https://youtu.be/AK1J8xF4fuk?t=705) to my mysql database. When I enter the values by hand to python code it works. However when i use python dictionaries for getting entries from gui like the video it's says: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':b_name, :b_category, :b_status, :b_author)' at line 1`

On video he uses SQLite this can be the problem but i'm not sure.

my code is here

```
# Insert Into Table
c.execute("INSERT INTO `books` (`bookName`, `bookCategory`, `BookCurrentStatus`, `bookAuthor`) VALUES (:b_name, :b_category, :b_status, :b_author)",
        {
            'b_name': b_name.get(),
            'b_category': b_category.get(),
            'b_status': b_status.get(),
            'b_author': b_author.get()
        })
```

Comment: SQLite, MySql, MariaDB... which one of these are you actually using?

Comment: And which Python DB API module are you using? Many vary in support of parameters. Please provide fuller code block include relevant `import` lines.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLdb [only supports](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) the `format` and `pyformat` [parameter styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). The `named` parameter style used in the video isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are not actually doing string replacement with your current setup, try this:

```
# Insert Into Table
c.execute("INSERT INTO `books` (`bookName`, `bookCategory`, `BookCurrentStatus`, `bookAuthor`) VALUES ({b_name}, {b_category}, {b_status}, {b_author})",
        {
            'b_name': b_name.get(),
            'b_category': b_category.get(),
            'b_status': b_status.get(),
            'b_author': b_author.get()
        })
```